# Is it possible that two different stochastic matrices have the same eigenvector both corresponding to the eigenvalue 1?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A and B are both [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) and both have a largest eigenvalue 1. Is it possible that the corresponding eigenvectors are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Let $A$ and $B$ be the $n\times n$ matrices corresponding to two different random walks $\bmod n$.   The dominant eigenvectors are equal (they are multiples of the uniform distribution) but the matrices $A$ and $B$ differ.  In particular: let $p$ and $q$ be two different probability laws on $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, for which $p(i)>0$ and $q(i)>0$ for all $0\le i<n$. Let $A_{i,j} = p(i+j\bmod n)$ and $B_{i,j}=q(i+j\bmod n).$